# Creating and receiving model objects

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

In the admin area, I can create an object of class User, while selecting the project and filling in the user field. Now I have a base.html form, where there is a user field, and the project field is not, because I am on the page of a certain project with a unique id (for example: the form is on the / project / 1 / page (id = 1)). The question is how to create an object of the User class from a form so that it automatically appears in the admin panel. I managed to do this if you ignore the project (ForeignKey). Tell me what to add?

base.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <textarea name="name"></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    user = HTMLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    user = Project.objects.all()
    return render(request, "base.html", {"user": user})

def retro(request):
    a = User.objects.all()
    return render(request, "create.html", {"a": a})

def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        tom = User()
        tom.name = request.POST.get("name")
        tom.save()
    return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'save.html', {'form': form})
```

In the admin there is a field project, i.e. drop-down list in which we can choose. Each project has its own id. When I am on the page of a certain project, I fill out a form and send it, it is necessary that in the admin panel on the page id selected in the project field.

Comment: You should look into model forms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: @IainShelvington I saw it before. It did not help me

Comment: You want a project dropdown on your page?

Comment: @IainShelvington No. On the page I fill out the form, i.e. field user and send. I need the user and project name to appear in the admin panel. There are many projects and each project has its own identifier.

Comment: @IainShelvington The problem is that there is no project field in the form, because I am already on the page of a certain project. How to transfer the project identifier from the page to the admin so that the project name is automatically selected in the project by identifier

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a page for a `Project` you must have the `Project` object or at least `id`?

If so you can add a hidden field to your form with the project's id

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="project_id" value="{{ project_id }}">
  <textarea name="name"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

This will then be sent to your view

Comment: Yes, the ```Project``` has the ```id```. What I have to add to views?